# Selecting triangle coordinates with all-integer centroids

Tags: list-manipulation, regions

Following is a list containing coordinates of triangles in 3D space:

```
list={{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 9, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 7, 
   9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 9, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {9, 
   7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {9, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 
   7}, {6, 8, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {6, 9, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 
   5, 7}, {8, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 
   3}, {4, 5, 7}, {9, 6, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {9, 8, 6}}, {{1, 
   2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {6, 9, 
   7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {7, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {7, 
   9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {9, 6, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 
   8}, {9, 7, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {6, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 
   5, 9}, {6, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {7, 6, 8}}, {{1, 2, 
   3}, {4, 5, 9}, {7, 8, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {8, 6, 7}}}
```

Furthermore, executing:

```
tri = RegionCentroid /@ Triangle /@ list
```

I get:

> {{4, 16/3, 17/3}, {13/3, 14/3, 6}, {13/3, 16/3, 16/3}, {14/3, 14/3,
> 17/3}, {14/3, 5, 16/3}, {11/3, 5, 19/3}, {11/3, 16/3, 6}, {13/3, 13/
> 3, 19/3}, {13/3, 16/3, 16/3}, {14/3, 13/3, 6}, {14/3, 5, 16/3}, {11/
> 3, 14/3, 20/3}, {11/3, 16/3, 6}, {4, 13/3, 20/3}, {4, 16/3, 17/
> 3}, {14/3, 13/3, 6}, {14/3, 14/3, 17/3}, {11/3, 14/3, 20/3}, {11/3,
> 5, 19/3}, {4, 13/3, 20/3}, {4, 5, 6}, {13/3, 13/3, 19/3}}

I see that, the triangle coordinates `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {7, 8, 6}}` have a centroid at `{4, 5, 6}`. How can I use Mathematica to display such coordinates and their centroids  side by side:

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {7, 8, 6}},{4, 5, 6}}

```
longlist = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 5}, {8, 6, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 5}, {8, 
     7, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 6}, {5, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 
     6}, {5, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 6}, {7, 5, 8}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {4, 9, 6}, {7, 8, 5}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 6}, {8, 5, 
     7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 6}, {8, 7, 5}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 
     7}, {5, 6, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 7}, {5, 8, 6}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {4, 9, 7}, {6, 5, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 7}, {6, 8, 
     5}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 7}, {8, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 
     7}, {8, 6, 5}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 8}, {5, 6, 7}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {4, 9, 8}, {5, 7, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 8}, {6, 5, 
     7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 8}, {6, 7, 5}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 
     8}, {7, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 9, 8}, {7, 6, 5}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 4, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {7, 9, 
     8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {8, 7, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 
     6}, {8, 9, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {9, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 4, 6}, {9, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 7}, {6, 8, 
     9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 7}, {6, 9, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 
     7}, {8, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 7}, {8, 9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 4, 7}, {9, 6, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 7}, {9, 8, 
     6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 
     8}, {6, 9, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 8}, {7, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 4, 8}, {7, 9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 8}, {9, 6, 
     7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 8}, {9, 7, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 
     9}, {6, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 9}, {6, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 4, 9}, {7, 6, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 9}, {7, 8, 
     6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 9}, {8, 6, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 
     9}, {8, 7, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 4}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 6, 4}, {7, 9, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 4}, {8, 7, 
     9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 4}, {8, 9, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 
     4}, {9, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 4}, {9, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 4, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 
     4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}, {9, 4, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 
     7}, {9, 8, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 8}, {7, 4, 9}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 6, 8}, {7, 9, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 8}, {9, 4, 
     7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 8}, {9, 7, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 
     9}, {7, 4, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 9}, {7, 8, 4}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 4, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 9}, {8, 7, 
     4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 4}, {6, 8, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 
     4}, {6, 9, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 4}, {8, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 7, 4}, {8, 9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 4}, {9, 6, 
     8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 4}, {9, 8, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 
     6}, {8, 4, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 6}, {8, 9, 4}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 7, 6}, {9, 4, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 6}, {9, 8, 
     4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 8}, {6, 4, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 
     8}, {6, 9, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 6}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 7, 8}, {9, 6, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 9}, {6, 4, 
     8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 9}, {6, 8, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 
     9}, {8, 4, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 9}, {8, 6, 4}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 8, 4}, {6, 7, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 4}, {6, 9, 
     7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 4}, {7, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 
     4}, {7, 9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 4}, {9, 6, 7}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 8, 4}, {9, 7, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 6}, {7, 4, 
     9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 6}, {7, 9, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 
     6}, {9, 4, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 6}, {9, 7, 4}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 8, 7}, {6, 4, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 7}, {6, 9, 
     4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 7}, {9, 4, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 
     7}, {9, 6, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 9}, {6, 4, 7}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 9}, {7, 4, 
     6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 8, 9}, {7, 6, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 9, 
     4}, {6, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 9, 4}, {6, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {5, 9, 4}, {7, 6, 8}}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get side by side:

```
tri = RegionCentroid /@ Triangle /@ longlist
e1 = Extract[longlist, Position[tri, {_Integer ..}]] 
e2 = Extract[tri, Position[tri, {_Integer ..}]] 
MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {e1, e2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Riffle[e1, e2]` does not give exact output. So used `MapThread`

### Old answer

```
Extract[list,Position[tri,{_Integer,_Integer,_Integer}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can easily add tri there if needed

```
p = Position[tri, {_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}]
Extract[#, p] & /@ {list, tri}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Flatten[%,1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you want to impress your friends and be cool, you can do it all in one command :)

```
Flatten[Extract[#, Position[tri, {_Integer ..}]] & /@ {list, tri}, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please see my output that I want.

Comment: Thanks. If the list has more than 1 triangle, how can I get all triangles?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter The same command should work?   Have you tried it on cases where there is more than one triangle and it did not work?

Comment: Please see long list.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter I just tried it on your long list and it worked?  It found 26 triangles. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10HHX.png)  is something wrong with the output?  this is the output you wanted, right?  May be you can show an example of two triangles found and how the output should show.

Comment: Pleae edit to get output side by side like my sreenshot

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter Updated to make them side by side. Hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

We use `Mean` to the points.

```
If[Mean@# ∈ Integers, {#, Mean@#}, Nothing] & /@ longlist
```

> `{{{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 7}, {6, 9, 8}}, {4, 5,  6}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 7}, {9, 6, 8}}, {5, 4,  6}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 8}, {6, 9, 7}}, {4, 5,  6}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4, 8}, {9, 6, 7}}, {5, 4,  6}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 4}, {9, 7, 8}}, {5, 5,  5}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}, {9, 4, 8}}, {5, 4,  6}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 8}, {9, 4, 7}}, {5, 4,  6}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 8}, {9, 7, 4}}, {5, 5,  5}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 4}, {6, 9, 8}}, {4, 6,  5}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 4}, {9, 6, 8}}, {5, 5,  5}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 8}, {6, 9, 4}}, {4, 6,  5}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 7, 8}, {9, 6, 4}}, {5, 5,  5}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 9, 4}, {6, 7, 8}}, {4, 6, 5}}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 9, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 
     7, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 9, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 
     6}, {9, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {9, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {4, 5, 7}, {6, 8, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {6, 9, 
     8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {8, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 
     7}, {8, 9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {9, 6, 8}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {4, 5, 7}, {9, 8, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {6, 7, 
     9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {6, 9, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 
     8}, {7, 6, 9}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {7, 9, 6}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {4, 5, 8}, {9, 6, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {9, 7, 
     6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {6, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 
     9}, {6, 8, 7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {7, 6, 8}}, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {4, 5, 9}, {7, 8, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {8, 6, 7}}};
```

---

```
Map[{#, RegionCentroid@Triangle@#} &]@
 Select[ContainsOnly[{Integer}]@*Map[Head]@*RegionCentroid@*Triangle][
  list]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 9}, {7, 8, 6}}, {4, 5, 6}}}